# Blazor Server Disconnect After 60 Seconds

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Experimenting with Blazor.  I create the (server) example "counter" web page.  Everything works fine in the development mode.

Then I publish the application to my web hosting service (ASPNIX).  Homepage comes up as expected.  Then after 60 seconds of non-activity, everything is grayed out and I get the following message:

> Could not reconnect to the server. **Reload** the page to restore
>   functionality

Is this normal expected behavior?  Anyway to keep the server connection alive?

Comment: Did you turn on WebSockets?  Any other server settings for the duration of a session?

Comment: I believe I'd need control of the server or server settings to make any server changes.  Again, trying to get this running at my hosting service (ASPNIX).  But definitely a noob here - and maybe don't know where to look.

Comment: Yes, you need to make some server settings. Ususally there is a dashboard, and yourprovider decides what you can set.

Comment: So I copied this thread to my hosting service, and here was their response: "Websockets are available, installed and enabled on all websites."

Comment: Is this shared hosting?  Shared hosting often moves your site from a virtual env to another, thus shutting down all websockets.

Comment: Yes, this is shared hosting.  This happens almost exactly 60 seconds after I access the website.  Here's a link: http://blazor1.gabelsys.com/

Comment: Now it seems to be working ok - hosting service said they didn't change anything - go figure